# Issue Exporting Grid View Data To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have to page in my web page that allows you to search for a list of names and it returns the results into a grid view. When the search result appears, the export button appears. I have the export button there for the user to click and it export the data from the grid view into excel in `xlsx` format. This is my current code:

**ASP**

```
<asp:TableCell>
     <asp:DataGrid ID="ResultGrid" runat="server"
      AutoGenerateColumns="false"
      EnableViewState="false" 
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell>
     <asp:Button class="myClass" ID="export" runat="server" OnClick="ExportBtn_Click" Text="Export" />
</asp:TableCell>
```

**C#**

```
protected void ExportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myexcelfile.xls");

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        ResultGrid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Currently this downloads a blank excel file... even though my grid view has one item in it upon search.

My additional question (even though I know it is frowned upon), is how to export as `xlsx` instead of `xls`. If I replace the `xls` with `xlsx`, it tells me it is in the wrong format when I click my export button (when it tries to open up in excel).

To wrap up, my two question are: why is it returning nothing in excel even though I have a row returned in grid view and how to export as `xlsx` instead of `xls`?

Comment: Your aren't exporting as XLSX or XLS. You're exporting to HTML, which is masquerading as XLS because of the file extension. That's also frowned upon, because the user will get a warning when they open the document that it might be corrupted. Instead, you need to find a library capable of generating actual Open Office XML Spreadsheet files (.xlsx) and use that. I'm particularly fond of [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), but note that asking for us to recommend a particular library is off topic.

Comment: Hmm, is there a fix with the existing code I have

Comment: I don't even understand your last comment. You're asking if there's a way to fix your code without changing your code? Clearly if you want to change the way it works, you have to change the code.

Comment: Correct, asking if you have any other input on how to fix my issue using my existing code

Comment: My first comment explains why your existing code cannot work. Therefore your existing code cannot and should not be used.

Comment: Then why does this work?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8_YrQVKe58

Comment: That tutorial is doing what I described in my first comment. It's generating HTML, then giving that to the user with an `.xls` extension. It's a terrible and hackish way of going about it. It is not generating real .xls files, which is a proprietary Microsoft format. I would not trust that tutorial or the people that made it. Like I said in the first comment, you need to use an actual library capable of generating Open Office XML Spreadsheet (.xls) files.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why mine isnt even returning rows into the excel file as is, like it is in the video?

Comment: Does it really matter? Like I said, you and the video's approach is a horrible one, and you should abandon it. But if I had to take a stab at it, I'd say you didn't bind any data to your ResultGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!!
the excel is blank because you are not passing any value to it

```
protected void ExportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
  ResultGrid();// Datagrid function to fill value 
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;    filename={0}", "myexcelfile.xls"));
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 ResultGrid.RenderControl(ht);
 Response.Write(sw.ToString());
 Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you're getting a blank Spreadsheet when you export to Excel because you're not doing it the right way.

You may use a third party like *iTextSharp* to do it correctly.

Actually, I wrote a working sample here in my blog: [GridView To Excel](http://dotnetfrommanila.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-gridview-to-excel-in-c.html)

Hope it could help you.

Comment: iTextSharp is a PDF library. While you may have found a way to get Excel to open the files you're making, there are much better ways of going around it. And linking to your blog is fine, but that can't be your entire answer. It'd be more appropriate to post that as a comment, as answers should be self contained.

Comment: Understand that. But what I did was to simply offer a solution (a working solution). I gave a link to a working sample to guide him in finding answer to his problem.

Comment: I understand you, but clearly you're not understanding me. The bulk of your answer can't rely on an external link which could break. You need to include the relevant portions from your link in your answer, or delete your answer and turn it into a comment.